# Multiple categories and labels for c3-angular-directive-c3 chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, c3.js

I'm trying to build a stacked bar chart for one of the requirement. The chart should look like as follows:

[image: Sample Chart]

I'm using c3-angular-directive library which uses c3.js to build the charts. The problem here is kind of multiple categories.

The first level of categorization is `Proj1 and Proj2` and the next level is `R1.0 and R2.0`. I've tried the following:

```
<c3chart bindto-id="stackedBarChart" show-labels="true">
    <chart-column column-id="x" column-values="R1.0, R2.0" />

    <chart-column column-id="Proj1Item1" column-values="10,20" column-type="bar" />
    <chart-column column-id="Proj2Item1" column-values="20,20" column-type="bar" />

    <chart-column column-id="Proj1Item2" column-values="30,10" column-type="bar" />
    <chart-column column-id="Proj2Item2" column-values="20,10" column-type="bar" />        

    <chart-group group-values="Proj1Item1,Proj2Item1" />
    <chart-group group-values="Proj1Item2,Proj2Item2" />

    <chart-axes values-x="x" />

    <chart-axis>
        <chart-axis-x axis-position="outer-center" axis-type="category"></chart-axis-x>
    </chart-axis>
</c3chart>
```

This results in totally a different way. I don't know on how to achieve to this.

Also suggest is there any other chart type which will help me to represent the data that I've.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can get exactly what you want using the current version of c3.js (0.4.10), specifically the multi-line X axis and the legend that shows a slice of each group, but you can get close.

If you're not fully invested in your existing directive, you can use [`angular-c3-directive`](https://github.com/atavakoli/angular-c3-directive) (full disclosure: I'm the author), which takes almost the same object that `c3.generate()` normally does and displays a chart from it.

```js
angular.module('app', ['c3'])

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.chart = {
    data: {
      x: 'x',
      columns: [
        ['x', 'R1.0', 'R2.0'],
        ['Proj1 (item 1)', 1, 2],
        ['Proj1 (item 2)', 7, 8],
        ['Proj2 (item 1)', 3, 4],
        ['Proj2 (item 2)', 11, 16]
      ],
      groups: [
        ['Proj1 (item 1)', 'Proj1 (item 2)'],
        ['Proj2 (item 1)', 'Proj2 (item 2)'],
      ],
      colors: {
        'Proj1 (item 1)': '#cc0000',
        'Proj1 (item 2)': '#0000cc',
        'Proj2 (item 1)': '#ff0000',
        'Proj2 (item 2)': '#0000ff',
      },
      type: 'bar'
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'right'
    },
    tooltip: {
      grouped: false,
    },
    axis: {
      x: {
        type: 'categories'
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.12/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atavakoli/angular-c3-directive/0.3.0/angular-c3.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div c3="chart"></div>
</div>
```

I find it a cleaner to move this sort of logic out of the view and into code; I've hardcoded the data & groups in my example, but you can conceivably create a service that constructs some or all of that `$scope.chart` object from data, which you can then use in your controller/view.

Comment: Awesome @tavnab. The demo of the chart looks good to me. I'll try and get back to you.